# After suspending child process with SIGTSTP, shell not responding

Tags: shell, process, c, signals

I'm coding a basic shell in C, and I'm working on suspending a child process right now.

I think my signal handler is correct, and my child process is suspending, but after that, the terminal should return to the parent process and that's not happening.

The child is suspended, but my shell isn't registering any input or output anymore. tcsetpgrp() doesn't seem to be helping.

Here's my signal handler in my shell code for SIGTSTP:

```
void suspend(int sig) {
    pid_t pid;
    sigset_t mask;
    //mpid is the pgid of this shell.
    tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, mpid);
    tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, mpid);
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTSTP);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
    //active.pid is the pid of the child currently in the fg.
    if (active.pid != 0) {
        kill(active.pid, SIGTSTP);
    }
    else{
        //if this code is being run in the child, child calls SIGTSTP on itself.
        pid = getpid();
        if (pid != 0 && pid != mpid){
            kill(pid, SIGTSTP);
        }
    }
    signal(SIGTSTP, suspend);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Am I suspending my shell along with the child, and do I need to return stdin and stdout to the shell somehow? How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's an old question but still I think I found an answer.
You didn't write your parent's code but I'm assuming its looks something like:

```
int main(){ 
     pid_t pid = fork();
     if(pid == 0) //child process
        //call some program
     else //parent process
        wait(&status); //or waitpid(pid, &status, 0)
        //continue with the program
}
```

the problem is with the wait() or waitpid(), it's look like if you run your program on OS like Ubuntu after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> your child process is getting the SIGTSTP but the wait() function in the parent process is still waiting!

The right way of doing that is to replace the wait() in the parent with pause(), and make another handler that catch SIGCHLD. For example:

```
void sigHandler(int signum){
     switch(signum){
        case SIGCHLD:
             // note that the last argument is important for the wait to work
             waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
             break;
     }
}
```

In this case after the child process receive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the parent process also receive SIGCHLD and the pause() return.

Answer (score 1):

`tcsetpgrp` is to specify what is the foreground job. When your shell spawns a  job in foreground (without `&`), it should create a new process group and make that the foreground job (of the controlling terminal, not whatever's on STDIN). Then, upon pressing CTRL-Z, that job will get the TSTP. It's the terminal that suspends the job, not your shell. Your shell shouldn't trap TSTP or send TSTP to anyone.

It should just `wait()` for the job it has spawned and detect when it has been stopped (and claim back the foreground group and mark the job as suspended internally). Your `fg` command would make the job's pgid the foreground process group again and send a `SIGCONT` to it and wait for it again, while `bg` would just send the `SIGCONT`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried doing what you say, but when I take away my signal handler the terminal just suspends the parent and returns to bash. I need the parent to keep running.

Comment: This is plain wrong, not catching SIGTSTP would certainly cause his shell to suspend and will let the children processes go on.
He needs to catch it so his shell won't suspend.

I am facing the same problem right now he faced earlier

Comment: @AdelQodmani, only the foreground process group of the terminal receives a SIGTSTP when you press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. The shell which is just waiting for the termination of the process it started, is in a process group that is not the foreground process group of the terminal. you can _ignore_ SIGTSTP if you like, that's probable what most shells do. My point was that you need to play with the foreground process group of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

i used folk with signals for make process pause and resume with ctrl+c

video while is running : [link](https://youtu.be/wY30F39R148)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void reverse_handler(int sig);
_Bool isPause=0;
_Bool isRunning=1;

int main()
{
    int ppid;
    int counter=0;
    //make parent respond for ctrl+c (pause,resume).
    signal(SIGINT,reverse_handler);
    while(isRunning){
        while(isPause==0)
        {
            /*code exec while process is resuming */
            printf("\nc:%d",counter++);
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
        }
        //close parent after child is alive.
        if((ppid=fork())==0){   exit(0);    }
        //make child respond for ctrl+c (pause,resume).
        signal(SIGINT,reverse_handler);
        //keep child alive and listening.
        while(isPause==1){ /*code exec while process is pausing */  sleep(1);   }
    }
    return 0;
}
//if process is pause made it resume and vice versa.
void reverse_handler(int sig){
    if(isPause==0){
        printf("\nPaused");
        fflush(stdout);
        isPause=1;
    }
    else if(isPause==1){
        printf("\nresuming");
        fflush(stdout);
        isPause=0;
    }
}
```

i hope that's be useful.

please comment me if there's any questions

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer the question here but this is what worked when I was stuck with the same problem. According to the man pages for tcsetpgrp()

> The function tcsetpgrp() makes the process group with process group ID
>   pgrp the foreground process group on the terminal associated to fd,
>   which must be the controlling terminal of the calling process, and
>   still be associated with its session. Moreover, pgrp must be a
>   (nonempty) process group belonging to the same session as the calling
>   process.
>
> If tcsetpgrp() is called by a member of a background process group in
>   its session, and the calling process is not blocking or ignoring
>   SIGTTOU, a SIGTTOU signal is sent to all members of this background
>   process group.

So, what worked for me was ignoring the signal `SIGTTOU` in the shell program, before I created the processes that would come to the foreground. If I do not ignore this signal, then the kernel will send this signal to my shell program and suspend it.